# Promise in Kotlin with Android

Tags: android, kotlin, promise

How do we achieve the promise pattern in Android?. Here I ended up in a situation like before taking a user to the Home screen I want to check whether all the necessary components are loaded or not? Something like

````
    loadLibA().
        then().
loadLibB().
then().
loadLibc().
then()
}```
````

Comment: There are a lot of ways of doing this, from coroutines to libraries like https://github.com/Shopify/promise-kotlin or http://kovenant.komponents.nl/

Comment: https://medium.com/@elizarov/futures-cancellation-and-coroutines-b5ce9c3ede3a

Answer (score 4):

In Kotlin you would use coroutines, which works like promises under the hood, but looks like simple serial code:

```
suspend fun loadLibA() { ... }
suspend fun loadLibB() { ... }
suspend fun loadLibC() { ... }

GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    loadLibA() // Execution will stop here without blocking, until Lib A is loaded
    loadLibB() // Same as for A
    loadLibc() // Same as for A
    startHomeScreen() // Normal call to launch Home screen
}
```

The sample code is of course simplified just to convey the idea. You can start learning about them from [official docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutines-guide.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement the promise patter like

```
fun postItem(item: Item) {
preparePostAsync() 
    .thenCompose { token -> 
        submitPostAsync(token, item)
    }
    .thenAccept { post -> 
        processPost(post)
    }

}

fun preparePostAsync(): Promise<Token> {
// makes request an returns a promise that is completed later
return promise 
}
```

Please refer this link [Asynchronous Programming Techniques Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/coroutines/async-programming.html)

Comment: What dependency is needed for Android? There's no such Promise Class :/

Comment: Looks like `Promise` is only available in Kotlin when targeting JS